# ARGV[] not accepting the argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, perl

I have a shell script that I am trying to pass a `date` argument to `ARGV[1]` but the script is giving a blank output

Here is the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%m%d%Y')
cat /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.$dt \
  | perl -ne '/STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && print join( "\t", $1, $2 ). "\n"' \
  | grep -E '(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)' \
  | cut -f2 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", '$ARGV[1]', $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $date_YYYYMMDD \
  > /tmp/output.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Let me explain what I am trying to do  here:

We have log files that get generated everyday with the name like

> `log.$AUTOSERVE.mmddyyyy`

the log file contains the data like below:

Made changes to the input date to get better understanding:

```
Time            Message           
____________________________________________

[11/16/2023 07:13:45]    CAUAJM_I_12345 The application has rollover

[11/16/2023 07:13:45]     CAUAJM_I_11111  The machine 111.test.com has lost connection
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: ABC MACHINE: 111.test.com EXITCODE: 1

[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 [222.test.com connected to ABC]

[11/16/2023 07:13:45] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    ALARM: JOBFAILURE         JOB: ABC EXITCODE: 1
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: TERMINATED      JOB: XYZ MACHINE: 222.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: 123 MACHINE: 333.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: 456 MACHINE: 444.test.com EXITCODE: 0
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: ABC123 MACHINE: 555.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 [222.test.com connected to ABC]
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: ABC MACHINE: 111.test.com EXITCODE: 1
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 [333.test.com connected to 123]
[11/16/2023 07:13:45]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: TERMINATED      JOB: XYZ MACHINE: 222.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: 123 MACHINE: 333.test.com
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: 456 MACHINE: 444.test.com 
[11/16/2023 07:13:46]      CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: ABC123 MACHINE: 555.test.com EXITCODE: 0
```

This shell script that filters this `log` file for MACHINE and STATUS search string and counts how many jobs have run on each machine

the output i am getting is :

```
            NP2     111.test.com      2
            NP2     222.test.com      2
            NP2     444.test.com      2
            NP2     555.test.com      2
```

i tried changing the `$date_YYYYMMDD` to `$dt:`

```
cat /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt \
  | perl -ne '/STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && print join( "\t", $1, $2 ). "\n"' \
  | grep -E '(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)' \
  | cut -f2 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", $ARGV[1], $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $dt \
  > /tmp/output.txt
```

But i am getting the below error:

```
Can't open 11152023: No such file or directory.
```

Given I have an environment variable `$AUTOSERVE` that provides the `NP2` value in this output, what I am expecting is:

```
11152023   NP2     111.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     222.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     444.test.com      2
11152023   NP2     555.test.com     2
```

Comment: I am not familiar with perl, but assuming in terms of perl it is fine to use `"$ARGV[1]"` instead of `'$ARGV[1]'` for you goal, you should use the former as the latter is conflicting with your current quoting in bash.

Comment: @TomYan I have tried that but it’s still not accepting the date argument..

Comment: Your are trying to use the shell variable `date_YYYYMMDD` as argument to the perl code. But this variable is nowhere defined in your shell script. Instead you have only defined `dt`. Apart from that your code use unescaped single quotes inside single quotes, i.e. `perl -ne ' ... '$ARGV[1]' ... '`. No idea what you are trying to achieve here, but this is basically trying to interpret `$ARGV[1]` from the shell and do string concatenation with the rest. Just skip these internal single quotes

Comment: Also, I'm not so sure you can use ARGV in the way you expect anyway when you are using `-n` at the same time. (And at least in the case that you don't use `-n`, `$date_YYYYMMDD` appears to be really, `ARGV[0]`, because `foo` in `-e foo` is not considered an arg in that context, apparently). See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944992/perl-n-with-input-from-pipe-and-argv) helps.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
DT=$(date -d yesterday +%m%d%Y) || exit
export DT
exec perl -lne '
  if (
    ($status, $machine) = /STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)$/ and
    $status =~ /^(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)\z/
  ) {$count{$machine}++}
  END {
    for (keys %count) {
      print join "\t", $ENV{DT}, $ENV{AUTOSERVE}, $_, $count{$_};
    }
  }' < ~/tmp/log."$AUTOSERVE.$dt" > ~/tmp/output.txt
```

Note:

- one MUST NOT use files with fixed names in world-writable directories such as `/tmp` (hence the switch to `~/tmp` here, or use a dedicated area in `/var` or `~/var`/`~/.local`/`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`...).
- there's nothing bash-specific in that code, so no need to add that bash dependency.
- with `-n`, extra arguments to `perl` are the input to the script
- as Chris already said, you had issues with your quoting.
- you have a `AUTOSERV` / `AUTOSERVE` discrepancy.
- `.` is a regex operator that matches any single character. Use `\.` or `[.]` to match a literal dot.
- beware that usage of `date` is GNU-specific. Not all `date` implementations support a `-d` option, and among those that do, it can be for something totally unrelated like on BSDs or they don't recognise `yesterday` (like with the `date` of busybox or toybox).  `perl` can also do date manipulation¹ if you need that script to be portable to non-GNU systems.
- You could easily change that to use a single regexp such as:

  ```
  /STATUS:\s+(?:SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)\b.+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/
  ```
- replace `keys %count` with `sort cmp, keys %count` if you want the list of machines to be sorted lexically.
- `exec`, common in wrapper scripts like this one is just to save a process. It tells the shell to run `perl` in the same process rather than in a child process and wait for it. `cmd` does `fork()`+`exec(cmd)`&`wait(child)`, while `exec cmd` (which maybe should have been called `nofork cmd`) is just `exec(cmd)` so even though it's longer to type, it's simpler/shorter to run for the system and uses less resource.
- `%m%d%Y` is not a very good choice of timestamp format. It's ambiguous and its lexical order (like in the output of `ls`) does not match the chronological order. `%Y-%m-%d` or `%F` for short is much better as it's universally recognised, and sorts lexically chronologically (at least for years 0001 to 9999).
- `cat` is the command to concatenate files, it makes little sense to use it for one file. Using `cmd < input > output` (or `<input cmd >output`, but *not* `cmd > output < input`) also has the benefit that if `input` can't be opened for reading, then `cmd` won't be run and `output` won't be clobbered.

---

<sup>¹ For instance here by adding `-MPOSIX` and a `BEGIN{@t = localtime; $t[3]--; $dt = strftime "%m%d%Y", @t}` or even as a hack just `-M'POSIX;@t = localtime; $t[3]--; $dt = strftime "%m%d%Y", @t'`.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

One issue that jumps out at me is in the second `perl` line:

> ```
> perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", '$ARGV[1]', $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $date_YYYYMMDD
> ```

You come out of single quotes just in time to use `$ARGV[1]`, so the shell has a stab at parsing it. Typically the shell variable `$ARGV` won't be set, so the resulting line passed to `perl` is this:

> ```
> perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", [1], $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"' $date_YYYYMMDD
> ```

and that's syntactically valid (but unlikely to be useful) so you won't get any errors.

If you remove the two single quotes in the middle of the line you'll almost get something that looks like it might be what you want. You'll need to swap out `-n` for an explicit loop to read from *stdin* so that your `@ARGV` value can be captured. Lists, including `@ARGV`, start from zero so I've changed that too.

```
perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { chomp; /^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", $ARGV[0], $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n" }' "$date_YYYYMMDD"
```

Here is an alternative pipeline for you that will take your source file and produce the stated output:

```
awk -v date="$(date --date 'yesterday' +'%m%d%Y')" '

    # Count instances of IP address for finished jobs
    /SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED/ {
        if (m = index($0, "MACHINE:")) {
            # address is after "machine"
            ip = substr($0, m+9, length($0))

            if (s = index(ip, " ")) {
                # discard trailing text too
                ip = substr(ip, 1, s-1)
            }

            # capture address
            seen[ip]++
        }
    }

    # Output list of addresses and counts
    END {
        OFS="\t"
        for (ip in seen) {
            print date, ENVIRON["AUTOSERVE"], seen[ip], ip
        }
    }
' "/tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt"
```

With `AUTOSERVE=NP2` and a suitable date match, I get this result from your sample data file

```
11162023        NP2     2       222.test.com
11162023        NP2     2       111.test.com
11162023        NP2     2       555.test.com
11162023        NP2     2       444.test.com
```

It's probably worth noting that the construct `if (m = index($0, "MACHINE:"))` is an *assignment* with a subsequent test for non-zero. If I had wanted a comparison I should have had to use `==` instead of `=`. It could equivalently have been written like this

```
m = index($0, "MACHINE:")
if (m<>0)
```

Comment: Hi @chris.. this awk script doesn’t give any output… do we not have to close the IF condition.. can you test this again if you are getting an output with the input I have given..

Comment: the output you are getting is different than what I am expecting..

Comment: No excuses. Just a typo! Really fixed this time, @NecroCoder

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is failing is first because you are exiting the single quotes:

```
perl -ne '[...] '$ARGV[1]', [...]'
```

So your `$ARGV[1]` is being seen by the shell and not `perl`. Next, you don't actually have an `ARGV` array here because you told `perl` to read from stdin since you're using `-n`:

```
$ perl -le 'print "$ARGV[0]"' foo 
foo
$ perl -nle 'print "$ARGV[0]"' foo
$
```

You can *either* use `-n` which means you pipe data or ask perl to autoload and iterate over a file, *or* you can pass arguments, but not both.

So, what you really wanted to do was:

```
export dt=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%m%d%Y')  
perl -ne '/STATUS:\s+(\w+).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && print join( "\t", $1, $2 ). "\n"' /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt |
  grep -E '(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED)' |
  cut -f2 |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && print join("\t", $ENV{dt}, $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"'  > /tmp/output.txt
```

Or, since you're already using `perl`, and assuming I'm guessing your data correctly:

```
export dt=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%m%d%Y')  
perl -lne '/STATUS:\s+(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/ && 
    print "$2"' /tmp/log.$AUTOSERVE.dt |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$/ && 
   print join("\t", $ENV{dt}, $ENV{AUTOSERV}, $2, $1) . "\n"'   > /tmp/output.txt
```

Or even:

```
export dt=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%m%d%Y')  
perl -lne '
if(/STATUS:\s+(SUCCESS|FAILURE|TERMINATED).+MACHINE:\s+(\w+.\w+.\w+)$/){
   $k{$2}++;
}
END{
  foreach $key (keys(%k)){
    print "$ENV{dt}\t$ENV{AUTOSERV}\t$key\t$k{$key}"
  }
}' > /tmp/output.txt
```